# in mail column in my gridview - how to send mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have `GridView` in my form that has column that bind to mail field on 
my database.

I see this mail in my `GridView`, but how to do that in mouse press I'll send mail ?

(I try the hyperlink - but still no working)

thanks

Comment: Can you provide your GridView code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="mailto:test@hotmail.com">test@hotmail.com</a>
```

Comment: but this is a simple hyperlink, i need it on my gridview

Comment: Do you need to send it on your server or the user sends it with his email program?

Comment: the user sends it with his email, how i can do it ?

Comment: Ok, so put the hyperlink into your gridview. Not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command button in the `GridView` to call code which will do what you want.